# Replace failed disk in RAID 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

two days ago one of my two drives in my software RAID 1 (that was setup using gnome-disks) configuration failed. I could not access the files in the meantime. After short research it seems that I have to replace the failed disk and rebuild the RAID to access my files again. So no problem today I got my replacement disk, removed the old broken drive from the raid and tried to add the new drive to the disk.

(Before I copied the partition layout from the working drive with: `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda`)

When I try to add a new disk to my RAID (that shows up in my gnome-disks) with `mdadm —manage /dev/md0 —add /dev/sda`, I run into this error:

```
mdadm: Cannot get array info for /dev/md0
```

The same thing happens to basically any operation using `mdadm` on my /dev/md0.

**How can I get my RAID back working?**

Some info:

Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit)

```
mdadm --version
```

*mdadm - v3.3 - 3rd September 2013*

```
uname -a
```

*Linux Z97X 3.19.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:43:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

```
cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdb[0](S)
      976627383 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>

mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : PC:0
           UUID : XXXXXXXX:7af47836:XXXXXXX:d7360235
         Events : 3569

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

*Why is **Raid Level : raid0** when I setup this as raid1 in gnome-disks / it's shown as raid1 in gnome disks?*

> And one question in general: My understanding when I put up my RAID 1
>   was that if one disk fails I can still access my data because data is
>   mirrored. But when the disk failed this was obviously not the case.
>   Why? Is my understanding of RAID 1 wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the drive you disconnected was the failed drive?  How exactly did it fail?  What was the size of the RAID volume?  Hopefully it was 456GB right?  If you had ~1TB of available space, then you somehow managed to make a RAID0 volume and  your data is probably gone.

Comment: Your understanding about RAID1 is correct. Somehow you ended up with a 1 device RAID0. You have not given enough information to try and figure that out. How big are your hard drives?